# How to exclude a page from redirection .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have placed this rule in htaccess to redirect any page to a subdirectory page.

```
RedirectMatch ^/(?!nz/)(.*)$ /nz/$1
```

I want it to redirect every `domain.com/anything` to `domain.com/nz/anything` with the exceptions.

Scenarios:

domain.com -> domain.com/nz/ - This is working fine

domain.com/any-page/ -> domain.com/nz/any-page/ - This is working fine.

domain.com/different.xml -> domain.com/different.xml -> This should remain as it is - **This is not working.**

Comment: You sure you have that in your `robots.txt` file?

Comment: Sorry about that. Edited!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you mean `.htaccess` and *not* `robots.txt`, you need to use mod_rewrite instead of mod_alias. So instead of the `RedirectMatch`, use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^different\.xml$
RewriteRule ^(?!nz/)(.*)$ /nz/$1 [L,R]
```